# Executing Multi cmd Command using JAVA

Tags: java, windows, cmd

Am trying to pop up a CMD then execute some Commands such as:

echo SOMETHING && echo SOMETHING && mkdir....etc

i managed to open the CMD but JAVA doesnt seem to recognize "&" inside string

the first command which before the "&" is the only being executed

any tips ?

```
    try {

    // Execute command

    String command = "cmd /c start echo hello baby & echo the world";

    Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

    // Get output stream to write from it

} catch (IOException e) {

}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's `&&`, not `&`.

A double ampersand is a logical *"and"*, a single ampersand means *"put the (first!) process into the background"*.

PS: By "cmd", do you mean the good ol' Windows cmd.exe? If yes, I don't know if those ampersands are working there. Try the PowerShell instead if so.

Comment: yes windows cmd.exe , am trying to past the commands directly to the cmd.exe and its working pretty good , only if the command declared as string in JAVA it do not recognize "&" nor "&&"

Comment: if i can rephrase the question: do i have to parse "&&" sign before declaring it into string ? (e.g: string tj = "tom & jerry")

Comment: This is Windows. The single ampersand does not put a process in the background. It has the same semantic as `;` in Linux/Unix shells.